# Facebook Page Reviewers through Graph API

Tags: facebook, graph

According to the Graph API documentation it should be possible to retrieve Facebook reviewER information for a page. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/managing just below the header "Get Page Ratings and Reviews".)

I am a page admin with all permissions checked.

However, if I curl https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/ratings/, no reviewer info is returned.

If I curl https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/ratings/?fields=reviewer,review_text only the review_text is returned.

If I access this same endpoint in the Graph API Explorer and specifically select the "reviewer" field on the left side, I get the message "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token".

Anyone know how I can retrieve this "reviewer" field?

Comment: Is your app reviewed & live? In dev mode you are definitively not supposed to get any such info, for any users that don’t have a role in your app. (And in live mode it might still be limited to users of your app, not sure.)

Comment: Pretty sure it's not reviewed, since I did not make such a request. So that could be the problem. Been pulling my hair out over the FB documentation! Cheers!